# Accessing the Session variables between two short codes in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, session-variables, session-state

I am using datatales JavaScript plugin and integrating it in WordPress. I will breakdown my problem in steps and approaches I have made to solve them.

1. I am using WOW plugin (html and js code!!) to write the client side html and server side php code and it works fine.
2. I accessing the **username** and **userrole** from wp login forms and saving them in session variables.

   ```
    add_action('init', 'myStartSession', 1);
    add_action('wp_logout', 'myEndSession');
    add_action( 'init', 'get_current_user_role',1); 
    function myStartSession() {
        if(!session_id()) {
            session_start();
        }
        if ( isset( $_POST['wp-submit'] ) ){
            $_SESSION['username']=$_POST['log'];
        }

    }
    function myEndSession() {
        session_destroy ();
    }
    function get_current_user_role() {
        if(!session_id()) {
            session_start();
        }
        if( is_user_logged_in() ) { // check if there is a logged in user 
            $user = wp_get_current_user(); // getting & setting the current user 
            $roles = ( array ) $user->roles; // obtaining the role 
            $_SESSION['roles']=$roles[0];
            return $roles; // return the role for the current user
         } else {
            return array(); // if there is no logged in user return empty array      
        }
    }
   ```
3. I want to access these two variables to set user privileges in datatables.The datatales code is defined inside WOW plugin, which allows me to write html and js (no php!)
4. I am using another plugin (XYZ PHP Code) to access these variables and I it is working as expected.

the code looks like this:
[image]

4. I use the shortcode from these two plugins on the same page, like this
   [image]

PROBLEM is that, I want to access the **session variables**  above inside the WP-coder plugin where I have html and js files defined.
How can I access these session variables inside the javascript code defined in WP-coder plugin ?

Thank you